# Вопрос по javascript и canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; 
var obje = {
  width : 20,
  height : 30,
  speed : 5,
  color : "white",
}
var arr = [];

for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  c.fillStyle = obje.color;
  x=500*Math.random(); // ВЫЧИСЛЯЕМ РАНДОМНЫЕ КООРДИНАТЫ ПО ИКСУ
  y=500*Math.random(); // ПО ИГРИКУ
  obje.x = x; // ПРИСВАЕМ ЭТИ РАНДОМНЫЕ КООРДИНАТЫ В СВОЙСТВА ОБЪЕКТА
  obje.y = y; 
  c.fillRect(x,y,obje.height,obje.width);
  arr.push(obje);
};
```

Почему всем объектам присваиваются одни координаты?

Я жду, что каждый получит новые случайные)

Comment: так у тебя ж всего один объект, у которого ты и меняешь свойства

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы каждому объекту, который я в массив добавляю, присваивались новые рандомные координаты?

Comment: нужно создавать каждый раз разные объекты

Comment: перенесите `var obje =...` в тело цикла...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это не поможет, потому что var не создает новую переменную, надо использовать let.

Comment: @SonicMyst как это тогда работает https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/LaowmG

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в данном случае и правда сработает, ошибься я.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый вызов метода `push()` в твоем скрипте, создает новую ***ссылку*** (на тот же самый `obje`), а не новый объект.
Объекты в JavaScript всегда передаются по ссылке.

Проще всего добавлять в массив новый объект созданный литеральной записью:

```js
const cnv = document.getElementById('cnv'), 
      ctx = cnv.getContext('2d'), 
      objects = []; 
const rndUInt = to => Math.floor(Math.random() * to); 

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let newObj = {
    x: rndUInt(300), 
    y: rndUInt(200), 
    width: 20,
    height: 30,
    speed: 5,
    color: 'green'
  }; 
  ctx.fillStyle = newObj.color;
  ctx.fillRect(newObj.x, newObj.y, newObj.width, newObj.height); 
  objects.push(newObj);
}
```

```css
html, body, #cnv { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#cnv { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv"></canvas>
```

---

Если же ты хочешь именно *копировать* имеющийся объект, то в данном случае подойдет такое выражение:

```
let newObj = Object.assign({}, obje);
```

Оно копирует все свойства `obje` (и их значения) в новый пустой объект `{}` - и затем, ссылку на него присваивает переменнной.